# Conversion from JSON extractor to Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

How can I get Token to reuse in another Request using Regular Expression Extractor. I want to use the gnerated to Token in different Thread Group. What will be the 'Regular Expression' to get Token Value.

My Response:

```json
{
  "Success": true,
  "StatusCode": "801",
  "MessageType": null,
  "StatusDescription": "Request Processed Successfully",
  "Data": {
    "Token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiI5OTIwIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJEQlNfMSIsInByaW1hcnlncm91cHNpZCI6IjIiLCJwcmltYXJ5c2lkIjoiMTA5IiwiZ3JvdXBzaWQiOiIxMDkiLCJyb2xlIjoiRXhjaGFuZ2UgSG91c2UiLCJuYmYiOjE2ODg4Mzc4MjksImV4cCI6MTY4ODkyMzYyOSwiaWF0IjoxNjg4ODM3ODI5fQ.fE5jtJTLD1sHrXByX_dXYVhJjz4suevug5wOaXV2rUo",
    "ExpiryTime": 72000,
    "TokenType": "Bearer"
  }
}
```

I tried to use Generated JSON forma Token from one thread group to another .

1. I took 'JSON Extractor' and put JSON Path Expression '$.Data.Token'
2. I took 'BeanShell Assertion' and script was '${__setProperty(token,${token})}'
3. In Another Thread Request I took 'BeanShell PreProcessor' and wrote script
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
   sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer" + vars.get("token")));
4. The Token is prerequisities for 2nd Request but Token not get

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access properties by `vars` object, it's for variables. In order to access properties in script, use `props` object instead.

```java
.add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + props.get("token")));
```

Comment: Hello lucas-nguyen-17, the  token is append with fixed Authorization header value, Final request header "Authorization: BearereyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiI5OTIwIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJEQlNfMSIsInByaW1hcnlncm91cHNpZCI6IjIiLCJwcmltYXJ5c2lkIjoiMTA5IiwiZ3JvdXBzaWQiOiIxMDkiLCJyb2xlIjoiRXhjaGFuZ2UgSG91c2UiLCJuYmYiOjE2ODg4ODI1MTUsImV4cCI6MTY4ODk2ODMxNSwiaWF0IjoxNjg4ODgyNTE1fQ.". where fixed value: 'koNeh2CyjnBZ9Tzsf0tePOOe7PulBoR9wNScCj7embk'. Unnecessary Text: Bearer. Ultimately it failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to replace `vars` with `props` in your code
2. You need to put a space between `Bearer` and the token value

   ```
   .add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + props.get("token")));
   ```

However there are several problems with your approach in general:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. If you run your request with more than 1 loop each iteration a new header will be added so you will end up with increased irrelevant traffic and who knows how does your backend handles such a situation

---

1. Replace your JSON Extractor and Beanshell assertion with a single [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code:

   ```
   props.put('token', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).Data.Token)
   ```
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) to the request where you need to add the token and configure it as follows:

   [image]